# How to say idiomatically: "analytical TV program"?

Tags: phrase-choice

How to say idiomatically: "analytical TV program"? If I understand right, you don't say like that in English.

For example, *Some people watch TV news once a week. Frequently it is the most popular **analytical TV program** with one host and several experts in different areas.*

P.S. Of course, I know about a phrase "TV show", but I think it doesn't fit to my request. I need a more intellectual term.

Comment: TV news has it's own category of current affairs

Comment: Since "analytical TV program" isn't an established category, you need to give us ***examples*** of what you're talking about. Note that ***documentaries*** often involve in-depth analysis of their topic, but they're rarely "interactive" or "live". Also note that ***chat show*** often connotes "low-brow", which is probably why Wikipedia refers to [*After Dark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Dark_(TV_programme)) as a ***discussion*** program. Maybe the difference there is a *discussion program* sticks to one subject per program, I dunno.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, a TV program with one host and several experts who discuss about X.

Comment: With what range of possible X's? Current affairs / politics? Celebrity gossip? Art? Popular science? [Gardening?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardeners%27_Question_Time)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Mainly about current affairs / politics.

Comment: That would probably be a "current affairs discussion program" then. But since almost all "current affairs" TV shows feature a panel of "experts", just the first two words should be enough. Imho, "intellectual TV show" is something of an oxymoron, and it's not much better if we change "show" to "program".

Comment: weekly television news program

Comment: @FumbleFingers - what if we change 'show' to _programme_ and consider BBC-2? Newsnight: Can Green Tech Transform the Economy? The chancellor says green tech investment will fuel the UK economy and increase growth but can the government do enough to guarantee success?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: If it's the BBC, I just call it all "propaganda" these days (even their comedy panel game shows).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - doesn't everybody call 'stuff they don't agree with' propaganda? Whether 'woke biased fake news' or 'rightwingnut balderdash'?

Comment: Those with access to the BBC 24 hour TV news channel will find several such programs covering topics such as in depth analysis, today's newspapers, science and technology film and the arts and more. Not to mention Panorama a BBC1 current affairs program launched 11 November 1953 and still going strong after nearly 70 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with the phrase "*analytical TV program*" It is quite natural. However, I don't think it has been used often enough to have a well established meaning of its own. Obviously it should mean a TV program that has an analytical nature or aspect. But it is not automatically clear which programs or categories of program you think that might be, without some examples or further definition.